# How can I know that which python my jupyter notebook is using and how can I change to use conda python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

Im trying to use torch in Jupyter notebook, but am not able to `No module named 'torch'` I found this
 [This is most certainly because your notebook is not using the same python as anaconda](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-is-not-found-in-jupyter-notebook/31860/2), and checked my python_version in Jupyter and got: `3.7.6` but am not sure how to check the version of python that anaconda is using.

**How can I check this? And then how can I make sure they are both using the same version?**

Comment: How do you launch the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can locate Jupyter startup script and check what interpreter it uses:

```
user@pc:~$ which jupyter
/home/user/.local/bin/jupyter
user@pc:~$ cat /home/user/.local/bin/jupyter
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

In my case it is */usr/bin/python3*, so it uses Python 3.

You can uninstall current version and install Jupyter for another python installation by executing

```
pip3 uninstall jupyter
/path/to/another/python -m pip install jupyter
```

Comment: Im not able t run the second command 'cat' only where python3 where python3
/Users/user/miniconda3/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

and also I don't know what other path to use...